# Laravel migrate error near BEGIN on trigger PostgreSQL

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, laravel

I have made database trigger in `mysql` and in laravel it is working fine, however when I moved to `postgresql` I am getting error:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "BEGIN"
```

(I am new using postgresql btw)

Here is the code I've made in migration:

```
DB::unprepared('CREATE TRIGGER histories_insert AFTER INSERT ON packets FOR EACH ROW
        BEGIN
            IF new.status = "pending" THEN
                insert into `histories` (`packet_id`, `message`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (new.id, "Barang berhasil di buat", now(), now());
            END IF;
        END');
```

I really got confused about it. Hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax and structure in mysql and postgre is different, in Postgres we have to write the trigger function (procedure) first then we called it in the body of our trigger

so after

```
FORE EACH ROW
```

There should be an

```
when event __type_of_event__
```

and then we call our trigger function

```
execute procedure __procedure_name__
```

Take a look at the doc about trigger [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html)

and trigger procedure [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-trigger.html)

Noted that `when event` is optional, and the name of your field inside procedure should be change into plain text, or wrap it with double quotes (if it mixed with capital letter)

Don't worry about the version of documentation, postgresql trigger is consistent across versions, hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for giving more detailed about postgresql... That really helpfull... :)

Comment: Nice, it's my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it into a procedure:

From the docs:

> PostgreSQL only allows the execution of a user-defined function for the triggered action. The standard allows the execution of a number of other SQL commands, such as CREATE TABLE, as the triggered action. This limitation is not hard to work around by creating a user-defined function that executes the desired commands.

```
DB::unprepared('CREATE TRIGGER histories_insert 
                AFTER INSERT ON packets 
                FOR EACH ROW
                EXECUTE PROCEDURE that_procudure_you_wrote_with_that_content(new)');
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Erdi, The syntax, and structure in MySQL is different than postgres.here is how you can write your migration for postgres Database:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION histories_insert()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF NEW.status = 'pending' THEN
    INSERT INTO histories (packet_id, message, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (NEW.id, 'Barang berhasil di buat', NOW(), NOW());
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER histories_insert
AFTER INSERT ON packets
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION histories_insert();
```